# What should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Most SE site chat rooms get a clever name at some point. What ideas do you have?

Answer (score 13):

## The Hangar

A possible idea for the general chat room

***This was the winning suggestion. Our Aviation Chat Room is now officially [The Hangar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation)***

Comment: As it will likely consist of *Hangar Flying* this seems like the most logical name to me :-)

Answer (score 6):

For mods, I would call it

### The Tower

For general chat The Hangar is hard to beat

Answer (score 1):

For the mod chat room maybe...

## The Cockpit

Answer (score 1):

### The Unicom

Of course

Comment: That might work for the US, but the term is either different or the concept doesn't even exist in other countries

Comment: The last unicom?

Answer (score 1):

**The Cloud**

would have been hip 3 years ago...

Comment: Wesley over on Server Fault likes to replace "the cloud" with "my butt" in marketing copy. The results can be... *amusing*

Comment: @voretaq Ho ho ho  (seasonal greetings)

Answer (score 0):

## The Runway

or

## The Tarmac

Comment: Project Runway? oh wait...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit US-centric, but for the mod chatroom:

## The FSDO

Comment: Or "The FAA"...

Answer (score 0):

## Pilot's Lounge

It might not be inclusive enough, but I thought it was worth adding to the list to be considered.